# app.activeDocument giving an error in indesign when opening document in the background

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am new to the scripting of Adobe products, when I try to use `app.activeDocument` to process the document after opening the document in the background. It gives an error.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.activeDocument` works only when document is open in front, by this it means when document is visible. 
If you want to access the open document when you are opening the document in the background, then use `app.documents[0]` instead of `app.activeDocument`. `app.documents[0]` also refer to the front most document but it also works when document is open in the background as well.

Try using `app.documents[0]`, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! This works. One quick question, it means `app.documents[0]` and `app.activeDocument` is same?

Comment: Yes, it refers to the front most of the document. But difference is only when that document is in the background it is not active that's why activeDocument fails at this moment.

Comment: Thanks! for the explanation.